# SQL Query With Scalar Variable Do Not Populate The Datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, ado.net

I have this datadridview that display data in a SQL database table. In here I have used a SQLDataAdapter and a DataTable(). Please refer the below code snippet.

```
private void btnSrcDataID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             try
             {
                 dgvInsertInfo.Refresh();
                 SqlComm = new SqlCommand();

                 SqlComm.Connection = SqlConn;

                 SqlComm.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE DataID = @SDataID");
                 SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDataID", txtDataID.Text);
                 SqlDataTable = new DataTable();

                 SqlAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlComm);

                //DataSet dsQryDataId = new DataSet();
                SqlAdapt.Fill(SqlDataTable);

                //Passing data to DatagridView
                dgvInsertInfo.DataSource = SqlDataTable;

             }
              catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
             }
        }
```

I think the issue is with either the SQL QueryString or SqlAdapt.Fill(), but I cannot understand the issue. Could you please someone help me on this.

Thanks,
Chiranthaka

Comment: Do you get any data in `SqlDataTable`?

Comment: SqlDataTable should store the data from the database table MyDataTable and they should filtered according to the query string in SqlComm.CommandText = (). But I am not getting any data.

Comment: I have tried the below code snippet as the SQL statement but couldn't get the result.
                `SqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE (DataID LIKE @SDataID)";
                SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDataID", txtDataID.Text); `

Comment: Can you add the structure of you `MyDataTable` and the Types of the `Column`s

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my case the error occurred due to a typo error when passing the value to the Scalar variable ***@SDataID***. So that the SQL statement's syntax is correct. Please refer the correct SQL statement below.

```
 private void btnSrcDataID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dgvInsertInfo.Refresh();

                SqlComm = new SqlCommand();
                SqlComm.Connection = SqlConn;
                SqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE (DataID LIKE @SDataID)";
                SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDataID", txtSrcDataID.Text);

                SqlDataTable = new DataTable();
                SqlAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlComm);
                SqlAdapt.Fill(SqlDataTable);

                dgvInsertInfo.DataSource = SqlDataTable;

            }
             catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Now the data is populating correctly in the DataGridView.

Thanks.